# Format DateTime.Now

Tags: c#, datetime

A peculiar request this one.

I am looking to compare two times in C#.

I have:

```
DateTime systemDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-15);
//which I presume subtracts 15 minutes from the current time
```

I am then reading in an ftp file from a Fedora server containing a date and time that I am reading in as a stream and converting to a DateTime

```
2011-03-17 09:00:18.000000000 +0000
```

I then parse this:

```
compareDate = DateTime.Parse(streamer);
```

My Question therefore is how do I format systemDate to be in the same format as the one I have parsed in compareDate? I am aware you can format DateTime but all of the sites I have seen so far dont have it in this format.

Thank you in advance, feel free to comment if you think I have missed anything :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to format `systemDate`, because you already parsed the date from the FTP server into a `DateTime`. You can just compare `systemDate` with `compareDate`.

Comment: so I have my:
2011-03-17 09:00:18.000000000 +0000
I then convert this to a String and parse it through the DateTime.Parse() method.

I can then simply compare my systemDate and compareDate ??

Answer (score 7):

You can do it like this,

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 1):

just use `var systemDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-15);` for your original one, then you just

```
if (DateTime.Equals(systemDate, compareDate))
{
    //...
}
```